# How to remove an installed Stylesheet?

Tags: front-end, customization, stylesheet

Recently I learned to installed a stylesheet, so I tried it on a random notebook. While the installed stylesheet did show in the drop-down menu, I don't know how to remove it! Since I won't be using this experimental stylesheet, can somebody teach me how to remove it? This is extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

Installed stylesheets are stored in:

```
FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}]
```

or `$UserBaseDirectory/...` if you installed it for a specific user only.

Since MMA can lock stylesheets or may not have rights to delete it the quickest way is to go there and delete it manually:

```
SystemOpen @ FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",   "StyleSheets"}]
```